# How do I pass params through an AJAX form to create.js while retaining the params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, parameters

I have some comments that have a vote score, and I filter them by recent and popular using a toggle. When I click popular, it passes sort: popular as params, and resorts the comment list based on that. Then when a user posts another comment using AJAX, i'm trying to keep the comments sorted by popular (instead of reverting to the default recent) by passing the sort params through the comment form to the controller, and on to create.js, where it sorts the comments based on the params pass in. This works once, but as soon as I post 2 comments, it reverts back to sorting by recent, because i'm not able to continue passing the sort parms.

My sort toggle:

```
<% if params[:sort] == 'popular' %>
    sorted by <%= link_to("Recent", video_path(video), remote: true, class: 'gray-link') %> |
    <%= link_to("POPULAR", video_path(video, sort: 'popular'), remote: true, class: 'gray-link') %>
<% else %>
    sorted by <%= link_to("RECENT", video_path(video), remote: true, class: 'gray-link') %> |
    <%= link_to("Popular", video_path(video, sort: 'popular'), remote: true, class: 'gray-link') %>
<% end %>
```

The comments form, where I pass my params as a hidden field called :sort - note, they are nested comments, hence the form_for syntax, but it should be irrelevant here.

```
<%= form_for [@video, @comment, , :html => {:class => 'form_height'}], :remote => true, method: :post, url: video_comments_path(@video.id) do |f| %>
    <div id="comment-form-errors">
        <%= render :partial => "/videos/comment_form_errors" %>
    </div>

    <%= f.hidden_field :parent_id, :value => parent_id %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :sort, value: params[:sort] %>
    <%= f.text_area :post, placeholder: 'Comment', id: 'comment-box' %>

    <% if parent_id != nil %>
        <%= f.submit "Reply" %>
    <% else %>
        <%= f.submit %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Then in the controller I create a variable @sort to collect the sort params from the comment form:

```
def create
        @comment = @video.comments.build(comment_params)
        @comment.user = current_user
        @sort = params[:comment][:sort]

        respond_to do |format|
            if @comment.save
                format.html { redirect_to video_path(@video.id), notice: "You said something. Let's hope it didn't suck." }
                format.js { }
            else
                format.html { render 'videos/show', alert: "There was an error." }
                format.js {}
            end
        end
    end
```

Then I order the comments based on whether the popular sort params was passed:

```
<% if @comment.errors.present? %>
    $('#comment-form-errors').html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => '/videos/comment_form_errors')) %>");
<% else %>
    <% if @sort == 'popular' %>
        $('#comment-list').html("<%= j nested_comments (@video.comments).arrange(:order => 'cached_weighted_score DESC') %>");
    <% else %>
        $('#comment-list').html("<%= j nested_comments (@video.comments).arrange(:order => 'created_at DESC') %>");
    <% end %>

    $('#review-form-errors').html('');
    $('textarea#comment-box').val('');
    $('#comment-counter').text("<%= pluralize(@video.comments.count, 'comment') %>");   
    $('.error-explanation').text('');
<% end %>
```

HERE'S THE PROBLEM: The first time around my server logs show params being sent as: Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "comment"=>{"parent_id"=>"321", "sort"=>"popular", "post"=>"c"}, "commit"=>"Reply", "video_id"=>"283"} - which is great, I post a comment and the comments, if sorted by popular, stay sorted by popular.

But if I post a second consecutive comment, it's not passing the sort params: Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "comment"=>{"parent_id"=>"322", "sort"=>"", "post"=>"d"}, "commit"=>"Reply", "video_id"=>"283"} - my comments reverts to sorting by the default, recent.

I don't know where to go from here. I feel like i'm missing something small, but no amount of searching around has found the solution. Can anyone point me in the right direction, I would really appreciate any ideas on how to get this working, or if need be, how to rework my solution if there's a better way to do this.

THANKS!

EDIT: With MravAtomski's help I was able to get this working. I changed my comment form to:

```
<% if params[:comment] %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :sort, value: params[:comment][:sort] %>
<% else %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :sort, value: params[:sort] %>
<% end %>
```

And in my comment controller create action I added:

```
if params[:sort]
    @sort = params[:sort]
elsif params[:comment][:sort]
    @sort = params[:comment][:sort]
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that after the first form submit the 'sort' hidden field looses it's value so it does not get sent it in next submit.

```
<%= f.hidden_field :sort, value: params[:sort] %>
```

maybe it should be

```
<%= f.hidden_field :sort, value: params[:comment][:sort] %>
```

because a comment object is being used in the form_for.

Also this is probably not the case but check if it is doing ajax requests and not html requests. If it's doing html requsests then it probably loses the 'sort' hidden value due to page refresh.

EDIT

so when page loads it uses params[:sort] then after create submit it uses params[:comment][:sort], maybe something like this can be used as quick solution:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :sort, value: params[:sort] || params[:comment][:sort] %>
```

Other solution would be to add a data attribute to one of tags that is not changed via create ajax request. i.e. form tag. add a data-sort attribute to form tag used to create comments:

```
<%= form_for [@video, @comment, , :html => {:class => 'form_height ..., :data-sort => params[:sort] do |f| %>
```

When comment is created don't change the data-attribute, it should only be set when user changes sorting and send it as ajax request parameter every time sort value is needed.

Comment: Thanks for the response, very much appreciated! I agree that I think the issue is that after the first form submit, the sort hidden field loses it's value. I tried params[:comment][:sort] and get undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass. I think that I want to use params[:comment][:sort] only after i've first submitted a comment, but I want to use params[:sort] for the 1st form submission (hence why i'm getting the error - there's no comment params for the 1st comment submission). I'm not sure how to facilitate this though or if it's correct - any other ideas? Definitely is an AJAX submission.

Comment: I got it working! Thanks a ton Mrav - I wish I could upvote you but apparently I don't have enough reputation yet. Using <%= f.hidden_field :sort, value: params[:sort] || params[:comment][:sort] %> gave me an error, but I realized it's because params[:comment] didn't yet exist, so in my form I set the hidden :sort value to params[:comment][:sort] if params[:comment] existed, otherwise, set it to params[:sort], then did the same in my create action. Just updated my question to reflect this solution. Thanks again for your help!